# Javascript - Mail Compression (Not the webpage)

Tags: javascript, email, compression

I have a emailing system in a program. The person writes a email, sends it to a database, and several people will be allowed to retreive that email later on. However, these emails are sometimes short but are sometimes quite long.

Consequently I would like to compress these emails before sending them to the database (in the javascript on the client side), then uncompress them when they are retreived (again in the js on the client side).

Are there any libraries (free) that can do this? Is such a thing easy to write myself?

Comment: I originally wrote an answer, but then deleted it when I realised it might not be what you want. Are you trying to reduce data download times, or are you trying to save space in your database?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Mainly it is to save on database storage.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be doing it with Javascript. It should be done server-side. So I think you need to edit and retag your question, so that it's clear what type of database you have and what language you are using to write to it.

Comment: I am using Javascript/Html5/PHP/MySQl/AJAX. (So from your answer I am guessing you cannot do the compression on the client's machine. I was trying to keep the the server activity to a minimum because its one of those cheap-cost-shared ones.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this at the client end, you can maybe look how [JSend](http://jsend.org/) works - it's not designed to save space; it's designed to compress data for transportation, but it's an example of encoding/decoding data. You will probably need to write your own script that does a similar thing.

Remember, by making the client do the compression, you need it to work in every browser. A server side script is much more reliable (and efficient).

You may want to look at [InnoDB Data Compression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-compression.html). If you can implement it, you might find that a native database process is much more efficient than anything you can do in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks - JSend seems to be what I am after but I can see your point about it should be done server side.